Splitting requests with subdomains up to two servers (tomcat)
I've got the following network structure:

An external request with subdomains should be routed to two different TomCat servers (depending on the subdomain). I currently have found a working solution with using different ports for A and B (Port forwarding; A and B build up a DMZ). But is there a better solution with high peformance where I use a bit of software (?) for performing the distribution.
Or should I use another scenario (scene 2) like the one in the second picture? What could be the ?-part then?

Thank you.
